# How to add non editable text view to a JDialog?

Tags: java, string, swing, textview, jdialog

I have a JFrame with a button labelled as "order". When that button is clicked, a dialog box comes up. This dialog box is supposed to show a summary of items that are ordered as a text view. I thought of having a string as a way to view the order, but that did not work out...

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
 import java.awt.FlowLayout;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
 import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

 public class PizzaOrder3 {

 PizzaOrder3() {

  JFrame frame = new  JFrame();

  JButton order = new JButton("Order");
  JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
  panel1.add(order);
  frame.getContentPane().add(panel1);
  panel1.setBounds(350,632,110,40);
  panel1.setOpaque(false);

  //Action listener for showing summary of the order
  order.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {

    JDialog d = new JDialog(frame, "Hello", true);


    //Where the coding for text view is meant to go

    d.setSize(400, 300);
    d.setVisible(true);       
  }
});

    frame.setLayout(null);                              
    frame.setSize(600, 700);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(40, 80, 120));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      PizzaOrder3 PizzaOrder3 = new PizzaOrder3();    
    }
  }
```

Comment: How did having the `JTextArea` "not work out"?  Didn't look right?  Program crash with stack dump?  Computer burst into flames? Or....???

Comment: JTextArea is just an example i used in code to explain what I want. instead of JTextArea, i want a textview, but im not sure how to code that in. I think i'll probably get rid of that...i guess it made the question more confusing ahah

Comment: You want to show some text that the user isn't allowed to edit?

Comment: Yep. The user should only be able to view the text.

Comment: Oh, no prob. Just set your `JTextArea` **not-editable**: `summary.setEditable(false)`.

Comment: OHH ok! thank you, worked perfectly :)

Comment: Myself, I sometimes simply do `summary.setFocusable(false)` because this way, it's not only not editable, but the user can't even give it focus by clicking on it

Comment: Ah alright..I 'll give that a go :) thanx!